# android - issue with auto scrolling in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have an `Activity` which serves as a music player. When it starts, a `MediaPlayer` object gets initialized and started. In the layout, I have `TextViews` to display the artist and the title. Those values (retrieved from the server) can be long so I added

```
   android:ellipsize="marquee"
   android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
   android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

to make the text scroll. There is a strange issue: when I press the "pause" button, the `TextViews` are scrolling, but while the music is playing they don't scroll. Any ideas?

P.S. I update the `SeekBar` every 500ms using a `Runnable`, could the issue be related to this?

Here's my layout:

```
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgCoverArt"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_header"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cover_default" />

    <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBarMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgCoverArt"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="9dp"
    android:paddingRight="9dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/pb"
    android:thumb="@drawable/pbhead" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvArtist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarMain"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvArtist"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTimeElapsed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBarMain"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBarMain"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
    android:text="02:54"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTotalTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBarMain"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekBarMain"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
    android:text="05:45"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/prev_btn_state" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/button_play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/next_btn_state" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Droidman, I am facing same issue. Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextView
        android:text="Single-line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget" 
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

add this your TextView,

```
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

is needed to scroll automatically.

More example are there in GitHub.

https://github.com/FireZenk/FireZenk-s-TickerText

https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition/blob/master/ignition-core/ignition-core-lib/src/com/github/ignition/core/widgets/ScrollingTextView.java

Hope this will help you.

Comment: tried that, nothing changed. Actually the text starts scrolling automatically, but only when the playback is paused and the seekBar is not getting updated. And as far as I know, only one View can be focused at a single moment of time, but in some cases I need to TextViews to scroll automatically.. Any other ideas?

Comment: took a look at the source, I'm having some doubts since the thing uses a Runnable and I already use one and a couple of other things.. (just memory management considerations, my player is going to be promoted as "lightweight and efficient"). Will leave this as an option, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in you `onCreate` method.

```
yourTexView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

I have also faced exactly the same problem. Solved it this way.