# How to make a text scroll horizontally and automatically in a TextView or layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-scrollview

Is there a simple way to make a text scroll horizontally and automatically in a `textView` or a layout ?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345903/android-issue-with-auto-scrolling-in-textview

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16371310/2345913)